# ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'public/uploads/2023-10-14T17-47-28.635ZScreenshot_20231014_192203_Chrome.jpg'

Tags: javascript, next.js, tailwind-css, enoent

I am trying to get a code that runs perfect in development but fails in production after I deploy to work in production.

> ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'public/uploads/2023-10-14T17-47-28.635ZScreenshot_20231014_192203_Chrome.jpg'

Code snippet for the file I suspect to be the source of the error.

```js
import multer from "multer";
const storage = multer.diskStorage({
  destination: function (req, file, cb) {
    cb(null, "public/uploads");
  },
  filename: function (req, file, cb) {
    cb(null, new Date().toISOString().replace(/:/g, '-') + file.originalname);
  },
});

const fileFilter = (req, file, cb) => {
  if (
    file.mimetype === "image/jpeg" ||
    file.mimetype === "image/png" ||
    file.mimetype === "image/jpg"
  ) {
    cb(null, true);
  } else
    ({ error: "Unsupported file format. Upload only JPEG/JPG or PNG" }, false);
};

const upload = multer({
  storage,
  limits: { fieldSize: 1024 * 1024 },
  fileFiter,
});

export default upload;
```

This is the error message toast

[image]

At first to make the code work locally i had to use the latest info available online and docs and solve it. It was some operating system incompatibility where the way that piece of code works in MAC-OS is not same for Windows which is actually the OS im using in development.

So I changed this piece of code:

```js
filename: function (req, file, cb) { 
  cb(null, new Date().toISOString()  + file.originalname); 
},
```

To

```js
filename: function (req, file, cb) { 
  cb(null, new Date().toISOString().replace(/:/g, '-') + file.originalname); 
},
```

This works well in development. I mean at `localhost:3000`. It is a full stack Next.js 13 project.

I am trying to upload product images to cloudinary but first im using multer to temporarily save the image in a folder instead the public folder called uploads.

```js
import multer from "multer";
const storage = multer.diskStorage({ 

   destination: function (req, file, cb) { 
     cb(null, "public/uploads"); 
   }, 

   filename: function (req, file, cb) { 

     cb(null, new Date().toISOString().replace(/:/g, '-') + file.originalname); 
   }, 
 }); 

 const fileFilter = (req, file, cb) => { 

   if ( 
     file.mimetype === "image/jpeg" || 
     file.mimetype === "image/png" || 
     file.mimetype === "image/jpg" 
   ) { 
     cb(null, true); 
   } else 
     ({ error: "Unsupported file format. Upload only JPEG/JPG or PNG" }, false); 
 }; 

 const upload = multer({ 
   storage, 
   limits: { fieldSize: 1024 * 1024 }, 
   fileFilter, 
 }); 

 export default upload;
```

Then upload it from there to cloudinary.

```js
export const uploadProductImages = async (req, res, next) => { 
   let product = await Product.findById(req.query.id); 
  
   if (!product) { 
     return next(new ErrorHandler("Product not found.", 404)); 
   } 
  
   const uploader = async (path) => await uploads(path, "buyitnow/products"); 
  
   const urls = []; 
   const files = req.files; 
  
   for (const file of files) { 
     const { path } = file; 
     const imgUrl = await uploader(path); 
     urls.push(imgUrl); 
     fs.unlinkSync(path); 
   } 
  
   product = await Product.findByIdAndUpdate(req.query.id, { 
     images: urls, 
   }); 
  
   res.status(200).json({ 
     data: urls, 
     product, 
   }); 
 };
```

when I deploy my project to vercel, I'm getting the same error again. Now when vercel is doing the hosting.

If you have come across this error, how did you got rid of it?

Comment: which technologies are you using? plain html and javascript or something else? ENOENT by itself is not much to go on. also please include error messages as text not screenshots.

Comment: Next.js, react, Javascript, tailwind, html

Comment: And which filename/pathname specifically does not exist on Vercel ?

Comment: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'public/uploads/2023-10-14T17-47-28.635ZScreenshot_20231014_192203_Chrome.jpg'

Comment: This is the error message

Comment: @JACOBKYULE please [edit] your question and update it with the information. imaginge coming across your question and evaluating whether you can answer it - havng to read ALL comments will not give you the best answer